# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2433: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm using the following code to write a text file to a variable

```
from pathlib import Path
paragraph = Path('myfile.txt', encoding='utf-8').read_text()
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\python\projects\vb\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    paragraph = Path('myfile.txt', encoding='utf-8').read_text()
  File "C:\Users\zagg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\pathlib.py", line 1133, in read_text
    return f.read()
  File "C:\Users\zagg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2470: character maps to <undefined>
```

I see similar posts with the same error, but none of the answers worked for me. any suggestions?

Comment: You gave the encoding at the wrong place. It goes into the `read_text()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `encoding='utf-8'` within `.read_text()`:

```
paragraph = Path('myfile.txt').read_text(encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, [`Path`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/af15cc534cdc13c610b92aeda56b41eaa99922b9/Lib/pathlib.py#L797) doesn't define an `__init__` and its [`__new__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/af15cc534cdc13c610b92aeda56b41eaa99922b9/Lib/pathlib.py#L808) ***gracefully ignores any `**kwargs` passed to it***. So the `encoding='utf-8'` in `Path('myfile.txt', encoding='utf-8')` basically has no effect whatsoever.

On the other hand, [`read_text`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text) does indeed accepts an `encoding` argument.